# Step implementation missing for ... In cypress ver - 12.17.2 and cucumber : 18.0.1

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, cucumber, cypress

my project structure.

[image]

error message

[image]

I am not sure why i am getting the error as i have followed all installation and steps properly.

i am expecting cucumber-cypress to work properly.

Answer (score 3):

There is one step you did not follow exactly, from this page [Step definitions](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/master/docs/step-definitions.md)

```js
{
  "stepDefinitions": [
    "cypress/e2e/[filepath]/**/*.{js,ts}",
    "cypress/e2e/[filepath].{js,ts}",
    "cypress/support/step_definitions/**/*.{js,ts}",
  ]
}
```

but above you show that the filename/extension part `/*.{js,ts}` is missing.

I would try following the pattern exactly, maybe that will solve the problem.